# How to retrieve name and revision of a Cloud Run service, from the service itself?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-error-reporting

I am using [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting) to report any error in my Cloud Run services and Cloud Run jobs.

In a Node.js application, you can instantiate Error Reporting like this:

```
const error_reporting = new ErrorReporting()
```

Which is equivalent to this, since `logLevel` defaults to `2` and `reportMode` to `'production'`.

```
const error_reporting = new ErrorReporting({
  logLevel: 2,
  reportMode: 'production'
})
```

In my error handler I am constructing an error event manually, so I can add some additional information (user, user agent, etc).

```
const reportErrorAndExit = (err) => {
    const event = error_reporting.event()
    event.setMessage(err.message)
    event.setUser('the service account used by this Cloud Run service/job')


    error_reporting.report(event, () => {
      // exit with an exit code !=0 so the Cloud Run job marks
      // this particular task run as a failure
      process.exit(1)
    })
  }
```

With this configuration, errors in a Cloud Run job show the user that encountered the error, but contain little information about the service that generated the error event:

[image]

Luckily, you can also instantiate Error Reporting with a `serviceContext`:

```
const error_reporting = new ErrorReporting({
  logLevel: 2,
  reportMode: 'production',
  serviceContext: {
    service: 'invoice-generator',
    version: 'latest'
  }
})
```

When you do that, the generic **Service** `node` will be replaced by a more descriptive `invoice-generator:latest`.

I thought that the Error Reporting client would have been able to authenticate with [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically) and retrieve the service/job name and revision automatically from its execution environment. But apparently it's not.

I think the only way to configure the Error Reporting `serviceContext` with the currently active Cloud Run service/job revision, is to retrieve the revision from the service/job itself. What's the recommended approach to do that?

Comment: Did you try to get the env vars K_SERVICE and K_REVISION and add them to your Error reporting config? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#services-env-vars

Comment: I haven't. I think it should be fine for a Cloud Run service, but it won't work for a Cloud Run job. I had a function that checked the presence of the K_SERVICE environment variable, and I found out that it is not set in a Cloud Run job. I was quite surprised. As far as I understand, Cloud Run services and jobs are slightly different "frontends" for the Knative API.

Comment: Did you check if other env vars were set? Did you check the metadata servers?

Comment: if you mean K_REVISION and K_CONFIGURATION, no, I still haven't checked if they are set for a Cloud Run job. Using them for a Cloud Run service seems like a good idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Cloud Run jobs, you haven't revisions, it's not a Knative service.

However, I listed all the env vars and I got this:

```
List all the env vars of the service

The value of "HOME" env var is: "/home"
The value of "PATH" env var is: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
The value of "CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX" env var is: "0"
The value of "CLOUD_RUN_TASK_COUNT" env var is: "1"
The value of "CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT" env var is: "0"
The value of "CLOUD_RUN_EXECUTION" env var is: "job-list-env-hnpq5"
The value of "CLOUD_RUN_JOB" env var is: "job-list-env"
```

The `CLOUD_RUN_JOB` is the name of my Job. You could use it as service name. You have also the version of the execution `CLOUD_RUN_EXECUTION`; it changes to all run of your jobs.

They might help you to configure your error reporting as you wish.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like what I was looking for. Where did you find out about those 2 environment variables? Do Cloud Run jobs run on a different platform than Knative serving? I saw `client.knative.dev/user-image` in my jobs YAML config and I thought they run on the same infrastructure of Cloud Run services.

Comment: I simply logged all the env var of CLoud Run job with a container. Knative haven't job management. It should be a Google made extension of the current Knative API, but only managed by Google